# Integrating ML with blockchain

Tags: solidity, web3js, machine-learning

I am currently doing a blockchain project on fake news detection. I have created all the smart contract part and frontend for the app. Now I want to use ML to detect fake news which is stored in blockchain. Is there any way for me to add ML algorithms with blockchain ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, ML requires a lot of computing power. Computing power can be very expensive on blockchain, so it seems like a very bad idea, or only for a rich person/group.
Also, your question is way too broad, this forum is here to help on specific problems.

Comment: you should see blockchain as a simple linked list data structure. Blockchain is just storage. Therefore there is no point in adding functionality to storage.